# HIghcharts, button text undefined

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've [trawled through the API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#navigation.buttonOptions) and can't find where to define the alt text of custom nav buttons.

Can anyone help out?

[image: undefined alt text]

Here's a sample of what I've got in my exporting options:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButtons: {
            enabled: false,
            menuItems: null
        },
        contextButton: {
            menuItems: null,
            symbol: 'url()',
            symbolX: 1,
            symbolY: 1,
            width: 1,
            height:1,
            onclick: function() {
                return false;
            }
        },
        'downButton': {
            symbol: 'url(img/glyphicons/glyphicons_200_download.png)',
            symbolX: 13,
            symbolY: 13,
            width: 26,
            height:26,
            onclick: function() {
                this.exportChart();
            }
        }
    },
    type: 'image/png'
},
```

Comment: Had it in my clipboard but forgot to paste it in! Whoops.

Comment: Please put fiddle link. it will he helpful to help..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9hxuS/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_titleKey` is what you want. See http://jsfiddle.net/x36qR/1/ for an example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9hxuS/

You can see that hovering over "Example" will show "undefined", hovering over "Print" will show "Print Chart" and hovering over "Download" will show "Chart Context Menu".

Have I done it incorrectly?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9hxuS/2/
You need to declare your alt text in highcharts[lang], and reference to the property name as your _titleKey. I did exampleButtonTitle as you can see.

Comment: You absolute legend. 

I totally wasn't hacking my way through and setting attributes in the DOM. Nope. No siree!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you define lang: { }
parameter in the chart object

then use the _titleKey: "example" in the lang to set the desired title

```
  .highcharts({

        lang:{
            example: "Title Name"
        },
```